# How do you get Lighttpd to compress CodeIgniter's "clean urls"?

Tags: codeigniter, lighttpd, http-compression

I was looking at PageSpeed on my test website and noticed that Lighttpd wasn't compressing my HTML (but was compressing my javascript and css files). I'm assuming this is because I'm using CodeIgniter and it's clean url system and since the requests don't have file extensions, Lighttpd doesn't have the rule to compress it. That being the case, how do I get Lighttpd to compress my HTML?

Is this something I shouldn't be doing? Or something I need to specially configure Lighttpd for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. If you are using 1.4.x you have to install the mod_deflate patch and use mod_deflate (which will be available by default in 1.5). Once you've done this you enable sync-flush and you're good to go.

For instructions on how to do this read more at: http://redmine.lighttpd.net/wiki/1/Mod_Deflate